# "Continuous" Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a "continuous" data structure taking a non-negative rational number, *x*, as a key. Searching for *x* as the key will either return the unique element that has *x* as a key, or else the largest of all elements smaller than *x* will be returned.

Here's an image to demonstrate, here where the search key, *x*, is 5.1

[Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jibkQ.png)

My proposed algorithm amends the normal binary tree search a bit:
Every time a right path is taken (so key is bigger than node) this node is added to a vector. If no node is found after the binary tree search, the largest node in the vector is chosen as the result.

**Is there**:

1. a (java) class that already does this ?
2. an easy way to "hack" an existing class into doing this ?
3. a better collection to do this ?

Comment: Please don't write your question so that it depends on off-site links to be answerable.  Some people won't be able to click through, and over time if the link breaks, your question will become useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem through the use of a [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html).  You can use `NavigableMap#lowerEntry`, which:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key strictly less than the given key, or null if there is no such key.

With this, you can easily grab the next-highest valued element.

Comment: perfect - exactly what I was looking for